# Como persistir campos estendidos do identity(Autenticação) .net CORE 5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, login, asp.net-identity, database-first

Tenho um projeto em ASP.NET MVC CORE 5.0 .

### O que quero fazer:

- Resgatar a informação **dadoAleatorio** do usuário logado,  em qualquer controller para inserir eles em wheres e creates.
- Por exemplo quero cadastrar um item, e nele coloco esse
  **dadoAleatorio** (informação do usuário logado)

### Com campos estendidos me refiro à:

- O identity por padrão vem os os campos pré-definidos, porém pesquisando afundo, vi que é possível adicionar mais informações ao usuário logado

Criei um modelo de autenticação básico utilizando o identity:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;


    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                                SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        return View(new ViewModels.LoginViewModel()
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(ViewModels.LoginViewModel loginVM)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(loginVM);
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginVM.UserName);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginVM.Password, false, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //Verifica se a url é nula, e se ela é interna para evitar open redirect atacks
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginVM.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(loginVM.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return LocalRedirect(loginVM.ReturnUrl);

                }
                
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário/Senha inválidos");
        return View(loginVM);
    }

    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(ViewModels.LoginViewModel registroVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = registroVM.UserName };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registroVM.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
        }
        return View(registroVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Eu precisei adicionar uma coluna extra a tabela dbo.AspNetUsers. Inseri via SQL pois estou trabalhando com database first.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também criei uma classe para realizar isso:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public int? dadoaleatorio { get; set; }

}
```

Ao injetar o identity em qualquer lugar do projeto uso esse ApplicationUser e tudo funciona tranquilamente. Mas em certos pontos do projeto preciso utilizar esse campo "dadoAleatorio" para passar como parâmetro ao criar certos objetos, ou mostrar certas tabelas. Como proceder?

### Edit:

Consegui recuperar os dados do usuário em qualquer controller utilizando:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

### Como faço para persistir esse dado?

- Atualmente a cada reload ou mudança de controller existiria uma consulta no banco
- Sei que os dados padrão do Identity são salvos em cookies. Tem como
  fazer uma extensão disso também?

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. O campo dadoaleatorio está permitindo nulls no banco e na classe não.

Comment: Corrigi a parte do null. O que quero fazer é o seguinte, ao cadastrar um item preciso Inserir esse dadoAleatorio. Ou seja preciso resgatar essa informação do banco. Sei que o identity faz isso com as propriedades id, email, etc. Quero saber se tem como eu fazer isso com o campo criado ou se preciso fazer uma consulta

Comment: O conceito de Identity é do banco. Se a coluna possuir o auto increment ela vai receber o valor de forma automática. Dependendo de como você está fazendo pra inserir no banco, o comando de inserção já retorna a modelagem, em outros casos você terá que fazer a consulta. Por exemplo: o Entity Framework Core normalmente atualiza a modelagem depois de um SaveChanges().

Comment: @M.Bertolazo  Me refiro a API identity de autenticação/autorização Nativo do próprio .NET https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @M.Bertolazo https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/06/extend-identityuser-in-aspnet-core.html segui esse tutorial para implementar isso. https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/06/extend-identityuser-in-aspnet-core.html

Comment: é basicamente só isso. Mesmo sendo *database first*, não precisa criar um *migrations* para atualizar os schemas? Quando adiciona o Identity ele faz, ao mesmo para o modelo do Identity, via *code first*

Comment: esse cara aqui userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginVM.UserName) não retorna o identityuser? se for, em tese daria pra castar ele pra um applicationuser e resolveria seu problema...

Comment: @LucasMiranda  Consegui recuperar o objeto user utilizando: 
 var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
Porém esse dado não fica persistido junto com o resto dos dados identity (salvos em cookies). Ou seja a cada reload de pagina ou chamada em alguma controller ele iria procurar no banco

Comment: @RicardoPontual confesso que fiquei um tanto confuso. Eu tive que inserir o SCRIPT do identity manualmente devido a alguns bugs já corrigidos. Todavia a model está coerente com o banco. Atualizei a pergunta para o enfoque que estava procurando. Como persistir essas informações durante a sessão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir persistir os dados **customizados** (campos adicionais da tabela aspNetUser) e utilizá-los em qualquer parte do código fiz o seguinte:

Primeiro criei uma classe que adiciona as CLAIMS.

```
public class IdentityExtensions : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityExtensions(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(type: "dadoAleatorio", value: user.dadoAleatorio.ToString()));

}
```

Feito isso basta ir no Startup.cs e adicionar a classe no configureServices:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
         .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityExtensions>(); //ADICIONE ESSA LINHA
```

E por fim basta requisitar essa CLAIM onde for necessário

```
var LoggedUserDadoAleatorio = User.FindFirst("dadoAleatorio").Value;
```